# mongodb issue while connecting

Tags: linux, mongodb, nosql

I cannot connect to the second mongodb instance on port 27018, the below picture shows my issue.
Please any help

[image: picture]

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: have no idea, but i edit the post now the picture is more visible now

Comment: Images of code/errors/tracebacks/data/etc. are a repellent to potential answerers.  Just copy/paste the text into a code block.

Comment: The MongoDB server log shows it launched normally (with a few warnings) and it is waiting for a connection. _"I cannot connect ..."_ Please show this.

Comment: Hello rick, 
 "waiting for connections on port 27018" still stuck more than 3000 s

Comment: could be the problem comes from resource limits ?  as shown in the last warnings

Comment: When the MongoDB server is launched and running, it waits for a connection from a client.  It will wait forever.  Have you tried to connect to the server?

Comment: How are you trying to connect? This just shows how you ran the database server which is listening for new connections. It doesn't show any problems yet. Are you trying to connect to a local database or a remote one, like on Atlas?

Comment: Have you tried using netcat to probe the port? 
```nc -v 127.0.0.1 27018``` 
It should show "connected" (hit ```ctrl+c``` to disconnect).